# Is there a way to save the location of an imageview?

Tags: android, imageview

I was just wondering if it was possible to save the location of an imageview so that it could be opened again, or redrawn, in the future if needed. Is there a nice way to sort this?

Comment: location on where?

Comment: The location of the imageview in a relative layout

Comment: Im not sure if i understand ur question. If its in the layout, the x,y of the view is always intact unless if you move it programmatically then you should use get the new layout params and save them

Comment: For example if a imageview is draggable and a user drops it in a specific location, is there a way to save the coordinates of that location so that if in the future the user wishes to repeat the action, we have the information saved and can just redraw the layout with the imageview in that location.